# Как написать регулярное выражение: найти все слова в которых буква "a" стоит на 5 месте и вернуть букву которая стоит на 6-м?

Tags: javascript

Как написать регулярное выражение: найти все слова в которых буква "a" стоит на 5 месте и вернуть букву которая стоит на 6-м?

Под местом понимается порядковый номер буквы в слове.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

а зачем тут регулярка? Перебрать в цикле

```
if(string.length>5&&string[4]=='a')console.log(string[5]));
```

Comment: Спасибо, ёжик!!

Comment: поправил индексы в substr

Comment: `string[4]` может попроще

Answer (score 1):

Если под "словами" имеются в виду строки в массиве, то вот:

```
^.{4}a(.)
```

Мэтчит четыре любых символа от начала строчки (`^`), затем букву `a`, а потом любой символ, и захватывает его в первую группу.

Если под словами имеются в виду именно слова в строчке, где слово это последовательность не-пробельных символов, то чуть посложнее:

```
(?:^|\s)[^\s]{4}a([^\s])
```

Мэтчит либо начало строчки, либо пробельный символ для того, чтобы поймать начало слова. Для того, чтобы реализовать этот выбор, используется не-захватывающая группа, так как нас не интересует этот символ. Затем всё почти так же, как и в прошлом регэкспе: мэтчатся четыре не-пробельных символа, затем буква `a`, а потом любой не-пробельный символ, который захватывается в первую группу. Вместо любых (`.`) мэтчатся не-пробельные символы (`[^\s]`, либо можно вместо этого использовать `\S`, если язык поддерживает) для того, чтобы в ходе мэтчинга не перескочить на следующее слово.

Способ использования второй регулярки зависит от языка. Например, в JavaScript будет где-то так:

```
function test(words) {
  var re = /(?:^|\s)[^\s]{4}a([^\s])/g
  var match = re.exec(words)
  while (match) {
    console.log('Word: "' + match[0] + '", letter: "' + match[1] + '"')
    match = re.exec(words)
  }
}

test('1234a5 000 ____aZ smth')

// Prints:
// Word: "1234a5", letter: "5"
// Word: " ____aZ", letter: "Z"
```